# how to pass structures like polymorphic when they are no polymorphic in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a scenario where a function accepts a structure (existing, existinghelper) which is just a data holder. but the function which process this data is tightly bound to this data. Now i need to handle extra data for which the structures needs to be extended (to_be_extended, to_be_extended_helper). What is the best way to acheive this?

The present code looks like below:
    struct existing
    {
    int a;
    int b;
    };

```
struct existinghelper
{
int aindex;
int bindex;
};

struct to_be_extended
{
existing e;
int c;
};

struct to_be_extended_helper
{
int aindex;
int bindex;
int cindex;
};

void fun1(existing& e)
{

existinghelper(e);
}
```

EXPECTED: I need the same code (fun1) to work for both extended and existing structures. logically like below

```
void fun1(existing& e ) // can be <to_be_extended & e> this should support both      existing and to_be_extended structure both.
{
existinghelper(e); // or to_be_extended_helper(ee);
//above line should support both existinghelper and to_be_extended_helper structure
```

both.
    /*
    //logically it should work like below:

```
if(type == existing)

     make existinghelper object.
else
    make to_be_extended_helper object.

The problem is they are not polymorphic and are just data holders.
*/
}
```

Comment: `if(type == existing) ... else ...` That's a very common pattern. This pattern is the reason object-oriented programming a.k.a. inheritance-based polymorphism was invented back in 1960s. If you don't want to reuse the idea of OOP, you probably will end up reinventing it, poorly.

Answer (score 1):

Overload the function for the different argument types:

```
void fun1(existing& e)
{
   ...
}

void fun1(to_be_extended& e)
{
   ...
}
```

If you have a lot of code that is identical for both functions, and you are trying to avoid code duplication, you can factor the common functionality into a function template.

```
template<typename T>
void identical_stuff(T& e)
{
    ...
}

void fun1(existing& e)
{
   ... non-identical stuff ...

   identical_stuff(e);
}

void fun1(to_be_extended& e)
{
   ... non-identical stuff ...

   identical_stuff(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make them polymorhic First Choice.
If its not desired add a data member type (possibly integer type) so if type==1
make existinghelper object.
else if type==2
make to_be_extended_helper object.

Comment: Thanks Ali, But the problem is you don't know which type the input miught be before run time and hence above won't work. I know best choice is to make them polymorphic but in my case it will cause a lot of code refactoring so i wanted to get a workaround if possible.

Comment: at run time how you decide the type, say based on user input you create an object on free store, right? you can also create corresponding type object based on user input , just ask the user to input its type also.

Answer (score 0):

make **to_be_extended** extend **existing**, and add a flag。

```
struct existing
{
    int a, b;
    bool isBase;
    existing():isBase(true){}
}
struct to_be_extended : public existing
{
    int c;
    to_be_extended():isBase(false){}
}
func(existing& e)
{
    if(e.isBase)
        ...
    else
        ...
}
```